# creating a button to update a database entry in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a database of ideas with a votes field.  I want users to be able to press a button to increase the vote count of an idea and then refresh the screen.  I have created a method called `increment_vote`, but cannot seem to find how to save the new vote value in my database.  This is my part of my index.html.erb code:

```
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= idea.content %></td>
    <td><%= increment_vote(idea) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Vote', ideas_path(:mode => "Vote"), :class => "button", :method => :get %></td>                                      
  </tr>
```

If I call the increment vote method from the link to vote code, I get an "`` undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass. Did you mean to_yaml ``"  error.

This is my method code in the ideas.controller:

```
helper_method :increment_vote
  def increment_vote(idea)
    idea.votes +=1
    idea.save
   end
```

This is currently causing the error, but it is increasing the vote of the first idea in the table.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `increment_vote` method from view, you need to create controller action for it and call it when the user clicks the link

```
# views/ideas/index.html.erb
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= idea.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Vote', upvote_idea_path(idea), class: "button", method: :post %></td>                                      
  </tr>
<% end %>

# routes.rb
resources :ideas do
  post :upvote, on: :member
end

# ideas_controller.rb
def upvote
  Idea.find(params[:id]).upvote
  redirect_to :index
end

# models/idea.rb
def upvote
  update(votes: votes + 1)
end
```

Comment: @MichaelBinks Great! Please, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped